# How to auth dynamoDB without Cognito?

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-iam

I know the best way to use `DynamoDB` in iOS is by `Cognito` as following code:

```
    AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider *credentialsProvider = [[AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider alloc]
                                                          initWithRegionType:AWSRegionUSEast1
                                                          identityPoolId:@"pool_id"];

    AWSServiceConfiguration *configuration = [[AWSServiceConfiguration alloc] initWithRegion:AWSRegionUSEast1 credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider];
```

The problem is the `Cognito` is not supported by China AWS Service. In order to use `DynamoDB`, I think I should implement a custom provider with `AWSCredentialsProvider` protocol. Is it right?

I have implemented the login process with a third part social network(QQ). I have the account id and accessToken generated by QQ.

the problem is how to allow user to access DynamoDB with QQ account Id and access token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When implementing your own `AWSCredentialsProvider`, I recommend the following approach:

1. Generate the access key, secret key, and session token on your server. You have many language options including Java, .NET, PHP, Ruby, Python, and Node.js.
2. Implement your credentials provider by conforming to `AWSCredentialsProvider`. Take a look at the implementations of `AWSWebIdentityCredentialsProvider` and `AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider` as examples. This credentials provider should:

   - Retrieve the `access key`, `secret key`, and `session key` from your server.
   - Persist them locally until they expire.
   - Return the credentials when requested.
   - Re-retrieve them from your server if they are expired.
   - Initiate the credentials refreshing process when `- refresh` is called.

Comment: Is there a way to generate token on iOS without my custom server? I have no experience to write server code. I have looked the AWS document and found the AWS Security Token Service(STS). Is STS could be used to generate token without my server?

Comment: If AWS STS [Web Identity Federation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_providers_oidc.html) suits your use case, you can use AWS STS from the mobile devices. Otherwise, the server approach is flexible and secure way to handle this.